# How to resize a range to stop at a cell with text VBA?

Tags: excel, string, vba, resize, range

I'm trying to resize a range to start at a certain point and resize it down until it hits a cell that contains the text "End of Data"

What would that/those line(s) of code look like?  I don't know if you can pass a string find argument to the resize function for range.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

These examples assume you're working in column A.

If you don't have any blank cells until the end of your data, you can simply perform the VBA equivalent of pressing Ctrl-Shift-DownArrow:

```
Range(Range("A1"),Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Select
```

Otherwise you'll need to first find the cell using a loop or the find function. Looping is a little slower but easier to code:

```
i = 0

Do
    i = i + 1
Loop While Cells(i, 1) <> "End of Data"

Range("A1", Cells(i, 1)).Select
```

The following guide is good for explaining the various ways to refer to a range of data in VBA:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg192736(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you could use this function:

```
Function ResizeRangeDownToACertainString(iniCell As Range, stringToStopAt As String) As Range
    Dim endCell As Range

    With iniCell.Parent
        Set endCell = .Range(iniCell, .Cells(.Rows.count, iniCell.Column)).Find(what:=stringToStopAt, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If endCell Is Nothing Then
            Set ResizeRangeDownToACertainString = iniCell
        Else
            Set ResizeRangeDownToACertainString = .Range(iniCell, endCell)
        End If
    End With
End Function
```

and exploit it in your "main" code as follows

```
Sub main()
    Dim myRng As Range

    Set myRng = ResizeRangeDownToACertainString(Range("A2"), "End Of Data")
End Sub
```

you may want to change the function behavior when it doesn't find the wanted string